# Creating tables and displaying textboxes in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Dataset from the database which i want to display. My aim is to display a month's data on an aspx page using VS 2005 with 5 days per each row. I have written the code like this but i am confused with the i and j. This code displays nothing.

```
if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Table table = new Table();
    table.ID = "Table1";

    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();

    // I am not sure what i and j should be here to display 5 per each row..
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (int j == 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j ++)
        {

             tb1.ID = "txtDateRow" + x + "Col" + j;
             tb1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Date"].ToString();
             tb2.ID = "txtDetails" + x + "Col" + j;
             tb2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["AmountSold"].ToString();
             cell.Controls.Add(tb1);
             cell.Controls.Add(tb2);
             table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    Panel1.Controls.Add(table);
}
```

If someone could help me solve this, i really appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is "j" declared/initialized?

Comment: Does it display "nothing" or does it display a `table` element with no rows?  The two are very different outcomes.

Comment: Why is `table` being added to both `Page.Form.Controls` and `Panel1.Controls`?

Comment: I just edited what j is. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Ram: The edited version is invalid code and isn't going to compile.  Can you share the actual code that you're using?

Comment: I tried various combinations for what i and j should be. I am helpless for what i and  j should be to display 5 per each row. :-(

Comment: @Ram - you know how to return results to `ds` but you don't know how to setup two for loops with i,j being counters?  This is now smelling like homework.

Comment: I am learning to create tables from code behind and display data which is retrieved from database. I always created textboxes, tables in aspx page, but this is something new, which i thought is important to learn.

Comment: @Ram: Being able to create loops is a first step, though.  The compiler will complain about the code above, and it will have little to do with `i` or `j`.  You need to first learn about things like loops and conditionals and the basic flow control elements of the language.

Comment: if (int j == 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j ++) // this is not valid, you need to change == to "=" for j declaration

Answer (score 1):

row.Controls.Add(cell) is missing. Bcoz of this textbox controls are not added to the table and you are not able to see anything. Add this line and it will help you see. Later you can think about i & j.

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop with a counter, namely, `i` but you test for `j==0` what is `j`?
Is `j` initalized somewhere?  Is `j` even declared?  If not, are you sure you don't want to test for `i == 0` ?

That is the reason you are not getting any results in the for loop.
The code:

```
 tb1.ID = "txtDateRow" + x + "Col" + j;
             tb1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Date"].ToString();
             tb2.ID = "txtDetails" + x + "Col" + j;
             tb2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["AmountSold"].ToString();
             cell.Controls.Add(tb1);
             cell.Controls.Add(tb2);
             table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Is inside a condition:

`if (j == 0)`

The question is does this condition ever happen?  If so you need to post more code.
Debug your code and set breakpoints and watch how it runs.  Per your edit you posted:

`if (int j == 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j ++)`

This is not even valid, I think you need to pick up a book on C# syntax before you tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what 'x' is supposed to be in your code. I think the general structure should be something like this but the code below will add the same thing for each column:

```
if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Table table = new Table();
    table.ID = "Table1";

    // j is the row index
    for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();

        // i is the column index
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
             TableCell cell = new TableCell();
             TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
             TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();

             tb1.ID = "txtDateRow" + j + "Col" + i;
             tb1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Date"].ToString();
             tb2.ID = "txtDetails" + j + "Col" + i;
             tb2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["AmountSold"].ToString();
             cell.Controls.Add(tb1);
             cell.Controls.Add(tb2);

             row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    Panel1.Controls.Add(table);
}
```

Comment: just being nitpicky, most people like to use i then j.  Since alphabetically i does come before j.  So i should handle rows while j handles columns.  But again this is just preferance.

Comment: @JonH, I agree, I would normally do the same, I was just being a bit lazy here - I took the original code and moved it around a bit so I kept the same variables. Might also help make it clear to the OP that he had the loops the wrong way round. In fact, in this situation I would probably call the loop variables row and column anyway.